# Can I append additional parameters to an oauth url?

Tags: parameters, twitter, oauth, request

I need to get data back when the oauth redirect returns from Twitter.  Is it possible to append additional parameters to the oauth URL?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can set a callback_url with paramaters when you get a request token and when the user returns to the callback_url the parameters should still be there.

Answer (score 0):

Each Twitter resource only accepts certain parameters. Required and optional parameters are listed on the Twitter OAuth resource pages. For example see [Public Time line Resource](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/public_timeline)